# Form clears parameter from given action url - PHP Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="{{ route('people.search', array_replace(Request::all(), [" type" => "customers"])) }}">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The following form action link looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/people/search/customers?countries=Germany&statuses=3&page=1
```

But when I submit the search form, it redirects to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/people/search/customers?search=test
```

Instead of including the parameters that were previously set.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Could be by using `$_SESSION`. Any idea how to? I could write you an example.

Comment: @RonnieOosting I don't want to use sessions for what I need

Comment: button missing type="submit" or any js catch on click ? in the form only one input name="search", so whats wrong, and the first url ?countries=Germany&statuses=3&page=1 where all the query string come from ?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to include the previous parameter is just by adding them as hidden fields:

```
@foreach(request()->query() as $key => $value)
    @if($key == "page") // Don't want the page parameter to be in there
        @continue
    @endif
    <input type="hidden" name="{{$key}}" value="{{$value}}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yes, you can't mix query string and form parameters.

Comment: @Devon Are you talking about what I did in the question or in my answer?

Comment: I'm talking about the reason why this solution works.  You can't have a query string on the form action for get requests if you have form inputs.